# Change the text color of one row of a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` which is correctly filled and it displays all its items. I was wondering how could I change the color of one of its rows (index = 0). I was trying to use the `ListView` and reaching its child using `listView.getChildAt(0)` but I do not see any method to change the color of the text (just for the background)

Just in case is needed I post the method that I use to update the `ListView`

```
String[] aux = new String[namesList.size()];
            namesList.toArray(aux);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.row, aux);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            if(from)
                listView_address.getChildAt(0) // Not a method which I could use
            setSelectNameListeners();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the color of a String, however you can change color of a textview.
A String only tells what to display, a textView will be responsible for how to display the information, now to change the color of the text you'll need a custom adapter and make that adapter return you the items, you get the 1st item and change it's color.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try this:

```
        String[] aux = new String[namesList.size()];
        namesList.toArray(aux);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.row, aux){
             @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
              if(position == 0){   
               // Get the Item from ListView
               View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

               // Initialize a TextView for ListView each Item
               TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

               // Set the text color of TextView (ListView Item)
               tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

               // Generate ListView Item using TextView
               return view;
               }   
             }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: that works however the code isn't top quality and not the best way to go.